# Is there Guava for C#?

Tags: c#, collections, thread-safety, guava

Google's Guava is very useful for Java programming. I needed an equivalent library for C#. I could not find one. So I have started a open source project to port Guava to C#. You can see the details for this project at its [home page](https://sites.google.com/site/nathanivijay/guava4dotnet).

Now, Questions are

1. How do I promote my project to get more developers / users / eyeballs?
2. Do people think that this project is useful or am I just wasting my time?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: hmm... I wonder if asking a question on stackoverflow is kind of promotion you asked :)

Answer (score 19):

I wouldn't call it Guava for .NET - partly because a lot of the classes in Guava simply won't be needed. A lot of the `Iterable` stuff is covered by LINQ, for example, and much of the resource handling is simpler too.

I suggest that if you want to create a new .NET library, you target *specific* needs - Guava is a grab-bag of utilities which have proven useful in Java, but the needs of .NET developers are different.

Comment: Thanks. I don't intend to do a line by line port of Guava. The classes that are not needed in C#, will not be ported to C#. I don't think C# has Immutable thread-safe (non-locking) collections. I think that these set of classes may be useful in C#. What do others think?

Comment: My only-half-serious answer is that Microsoft already did this - they just added some interesting syntax and called it F#.

Comment: @Vijay - .Net 4.0 does have such collections in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace.

Comment: @codekaizen: Not thread-safe ones. The concurrent collections are all mutable, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @JonSkeet - not immutable, no (though immutable collection interfaces are in .Net 4.5), however they are thread-safe (meaning multiple concurrent threads can access and mutate them without causing the structure to transition to an invalid state), are they not?

Comment: @codekaizen: Yes, they're thread-safe - but in his comment Vijay specifically asked for immutable ones. It's a big difference in terms of usability... I love immutability :)

Comment: com.google.common.base.Joiner would be very useful in .Net

Comment: It's true that Guava is Java's prosthetic (coming from C#, I can't really wrap my head around how verbose and unfriendly Java is), yet I think it still contains a lot of interesting collections that .NET doesn't have, such as `RangeSet` or `Table`. Or their neat hashcode generator... way simplier than fiddling with primes and `unchecked`